# Sequelize 4.42.0: Setting an instance method returns "not a function" error

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

My console shows the following error:

```
POST /log-in 200 637.310 ms - 42
Unhandled rejection TypeError: models.UserAccount.setJwTokenCookie is not a function
    at models.UserAccount.findOne.then.userRecord (/home/owner/PhpstormProjects/reportingAreaApi/routes/index.js:99:33)
    at tryCatcher (/home/owner/PhpstormProjects/reportingAreaApi/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
```

I have been attempting to add instance methods to the UserAccount model definition. The method `setJwTokenCookie` appears to be at fault below:

```
'use strict';
require('dotenv').load();
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs'),
      jsonWebToken = require('jsonwebtoken'),
      moment = require('moment'); 


module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const UserAccount = sequelize.define('UserAccount', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  });

    // cookie-setter
  UserAccount.prototype.setJwTokenCookie = (responseLocal, userId) => {
    // generate a new jwt encoded with userId:
    const signedToken = jsonWebToken.sign({
      data: {
        userId : userId
      }
    }, <secret>); 

    const dateIn10Years = new moment()
      .add(10, "years").toDate();

    responseLocal.cookie('jwTokenCookie', signedToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      expires : dateIn10Years
    })
  };

  return UserAccount;
};
```

I am trying to follow the instance method format shown here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#expansion-of-models

Does anyone know the source of this error? I am working inside of an Express.js project and the error fires when a post request is made to the relevant route handler.

The method is called here:

```
router.post('/log-in', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
  // get the user's Id. Then set the cookie with it
  models.UserAccount.findOne({ where : { username : req.body.username }})
    .then(userRecord => {
      const { userId } = userRecord;
      return models.UserAccount.setJwTokenCookie(res, userId);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined it as a instance method:

```
UserAccount.prototype.setJwTokenCookie
```

But are calling it as a class method:

```
models.UserAccount.setJwTokenCookie
```

It should just be:

```
.then(userRecord => {
  const { userId } = userRecord;
  return userRecord.setJwTokenCookie(res, userId);
});
```